# Forward 12m EPS Growth and its Earning Revision using Bloomberg

Tags: r, bloomberg, excel

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use data from Bloomberg to create some analysis on a company's performance using Excel/R.

How can I find the Forward 12m EPS Growth, its 1m Earning Revision and 3m Earning Revision?

**Question 1:** Is the **Forward 12m EPS Growth** obtained directly using the field `BEST_EPS_YOY_GTH`?

**Question 2:** How then do we find the **1m Earning Revision** and **3m Earning Revision**?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to estimate Forward 12m EPS Growth using a single bloomberg formula with overrides. `BEST_EPS_YOY_GTH` does not allow BF overrides, only FY. Therefore you cannot keep 12m horizon constant. One solution would be to get `BEST_EPS` with BF1 override and compare this number with current EPS. For historical analysis, retrieve historical EPS vector and compare it with `BEST_EPS`.

With respect to `Earnings revisions` you simply have to estimate the chg in  `BEST_EPS` over any specified period (1mo,3mo etc.).